# How to continue evaluating a binary tree in scheme

Tags: scheme

I need to evaluate a scheme function that inputs a number and a binary tree and it outputs the data expression in the binary tree that is of the same depth as the number. For example the root of a tree is 1 and the root of the sub trees are 2 and so on.

This is what I have so far and I keep getting the error message `Error in null?: expected a list; got '1'.` (This is another method of solving a problem that I had asked earlier about) Could you explain this using the terms that I have already used as I am new to scheme programming.

Thank you

```
(define fetch-exp (λ (n bt) 
  (cond [(not (deep-enough? n bt)) ▽#f]
        [(one? n) (root bt)]
        [(deep-enough? n (left-tree bt)) 
         (fetch-exp (left-tree bt) (sub1 n))] 
        [(deep-enough? n (right-tree bt)) 
         (fetch-exp (right-tree bt) sub1 n)] 
        [else ▽#f]))) 

(define deep-enough? 
 (λ (n bt) 
  (cond [(> (tree-depth bt) n) ▽#t] 
        [(equal? (tree-depth bt) n) ▽#t]      
        [else ▽#f])))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the recursion you are still passing the arguments back to fetch-expression in the wrong order. The value for the new n first and then the new tree.

You are still potentially calling tree-depth twice within deep-enough?

```
(define deep-enough? 
 (λ (n bt) 
  (if (>= (tree-depth bt) n) 
      true
      false)))
```

Fixes it

But take a look at my answer to your other question there's no need to have a separate function to count the depth. Just start traversing it with a function that can backtrack. (signal an error to the caller, and have the caller try a different path if any valid ones have not yet been tried)